# Firebase web modular api error : can't assign to property "callback" on "captcha-container": not an object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

This code give me error:

> can't assign to property "callback" on "captcha-container": not an object

```
const auth = getAuth();
const appVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(auth, 'captcha-container', {
     'callback': (response) => {
         console.log(response)
      },
});
```

here is html

```
<div id="captcha-container"></div>
```

can someone help me what is wrong and how to fix?